# Wrong output of coverting NSString to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I try to convert my `NSString` to `NSDate` object, but `NSDateFormatter` returns me a strange value. I want `01/07/2016` but it will return wrong output. Output is:

> Today: 2015-12-20 00:00:00 +0000

Here is code:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSInteger day = 01;
NSInteger week = 07;
NSInteger year = [components year];

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld/%ld/%ld",  (long)week,(long)day, (long)year];
NSLog(@"Min Date: %@",string);

NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformate setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[dateformate setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YY"];

strMinDate = [dateformate dateFromString:string];
NSLog(@"Today: %@", strMinDate);
```

Comment: Try to nslog like :   NSLog(@"date is %@",[dateformate stringFromDate:strMinDate]);

Comment: Do you know what octal numbers are? 01 and 07 are octal numbers. Don't use them unless you know what they are.

Comment: %zd prints NSInteger correctly both on 32 and 64 bit without needing a stupid cast.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of things to cleanup here.

1. Rename your `week` variable to `month`.
2. Your date format is wrong. It should be `@"MM/dd/yyyy`.
3. Don't use octal numbers.

That should fix your code as written.

However, there is no reason to get an `NSDateFormatter` involved at all. Just create a new date directly from your updated `NSDateComponents`.

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];

components.day = 1;
components.month = 7; // July

NSDate *minDate = [NSCalendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

This will give you a new date in local time.

Once you have the proper `NSDate`, you can now format it into a string of your choosing using an `NSDateFormatter`.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy"];
NSString *dayMonthYearStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:minDate];
```

Comment: Doesn't Perfect answer to question because question is string to date convert.

Comment: I need date like  this 01/07/16 (Date/month/two digit of year.)

Comment: @NipulDaki What is your final goal? Is it to end up with an `NSDate` containing a specific day and month for the current year, or is it to end up with an `NSString` containing a specific day and month for the current year in the format dd/MM/yy?

Comment: @Bhadresh No. The question starts with the current date as an `NSDate`. And the question ends with a new `NSDate`. The question first converts the current `NSDate` into components, changes the components, creates a string from the components, and finally tries to creates the new `NSDate` from the string. My answer shows how to convert the original `NSDate` to the new `NSDate` without the need of using a needless `NSString` in the middle. But I also explained how to fix the current code as-is if desired. I posted an update showing how to get a  string from the new date if desired.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSInteger day = 01;
NSInteger month = 07;
NSInteger year = [components year];

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld/%ld/%ld",  (long)year,(long)month, (long)day];

NSLog(@"Min Date: %@",string);
NSString *date_str = string;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:gmt];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:date_str];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```